# Is it fair to use ironic comments on "gimme codez" questions?

Tags: discussion, comments

For instance, I stumble on this question: [`Create Data Based on Date C#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699581/create-data-based-on-date-c-sharp)

In the "gimme codez" questions we'll find a "I want a (*put something here*)" without research or even a minimum technical glimpse.

Is it fair to use ironic comments to make a point, like "I also want a vanilla ice cream, but it seems we both won't get what we want"? Is another comment type recommended? Or just cast a down/closing vote and move on?

Comment: Just down and close vote and move on. Don't create noise.

Comment: In all fairness, I am guilty of that as well - sometimes. (I'm hesitant to browse my Comment history because it's kind of embarrasing.) But I'm trying, Ringo, I'm trying really hard to be the shepherd.

Comment: No, it isn't any more fair than it would be on a good question. Be nice. Voting and moderation procedures exist to take care of bad questions.

Comment: I sometimes write such comments to use them to show OP how their question gets read from others and what they have to change to get a good question out of it.

Comment: "Is it fair to use ironic comments to make a point" (opinion) No. Downvote, report, vote to close and move on. Chatting, making noise and trying to be a smart#ss is a waste of everyone's time. Learning programming takes years. You can't expect a complete newbie to instantly reach enlightenment and acquire understanding of all the stuff you accumulated over years just because someone tried to make fun of them.

Comment: "These people don't care how you react; they're looking for the one guy that will actually do their homework for them (some people will). Consequently, your negative comment will have no effect on the OP, and will only succeed in irritating your fellow community members and alienating new visitors to the site..." ([Programmers.SE and the Summer of Love](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3837/31260))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not appropriate on any question. Just vote to close (and down vote if you want).

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you want to build the community of good users, or just blow away some person who got off to a bad start.

I do the `"Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a moment to review the [help] - your question currently suffers from ... "`  shtick, because there's a real chance that the person didn't know, and will learn if they are welcomed.

It's hard to see how giving someone a dose of irony and sarcasm is showing them how we'd like behaviour to be at StackOverflow.

Comment: Step #1 for me is checking if that person bothered to read the [tour] ("it's friendly! really short as well!").

Comment: @Jongware I guess we'll all have different opinions about the best way to educate new people who ask bad questions.  I think that the "tour" is more oriented towards explaining why you might be interested to come and participate here.   Having come, and tried participating but not done well, I think the new person's attention is better directed to [help/how-to-ask] and similar.

Answer (score 1):

I've adopted the [Have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), [how to get over being lazy](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/too-lazy-to-do-programming) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and alternate between them. [For Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692468/mvc-5-simple-user-authentication?lq=1)